# How do I train CNN using unlabelled images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train image classificator using CNN GoogleNet Inception. I have some labeled images(cca 1000 per category) and much more unlabeled images. So far have I used just labeled images and I got good accuracy. I am just not sure if it is possible to use somehow unlabeled images.

The only information about them is, that there are always some images(1-10) in one directory. And images in one directory belong to same class.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Keras ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). Its a convenience function that reads images from subdirectories that correspondend to classes.

Even if you don´t use Keras for training you could do a dummy run to generate labels for your unlabeled images and then use these in your neural network architecture.

You can also look into [pseudo labelling](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280581078_Pseudo-Label_The_Simple_and_Efficient_Semi-Supervised_Learning_Method_for_Deep_Neural_Networks) for images for which you don´t have any information regarding the content.